# Why does python think each character in my list is an element?

Tags: python, list, csv

I wanted to use an Excel file in Python, so I converted it to csv. I couldn't read it properly as I usually read csv files, so I read it like a txt file.

I've read each row and appended them to a list, and now I want to make a list with a particular column. When I write my code to retrieve the elements in position "col number", I get a single letter instead of getting a string with the words that are between commas, which I need to put in the column list.

I think it might be a problem from reading the file, but I'm really not sure. Is there a better way to convert an xls to csv for Python, or to read the file into my list? Can I combine letters to make one element out of several elements in a list?

Thank you!

Comment: How can we hope to answer this without seeing the code? Especially since you said you've ditched the approach of reading as a CSV and read it as a text file

Comment: Please follow the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to share an example of what you've tried and what are your expectations from the code so that we may help you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would it be possible to show your code in the question, preferably as a [Minimal, Viable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It makes it so much easier to solve your question.

Answer (score 3):

There are no need to change `.xlsx` to `.csv` or `.txt`. you can read excel file in python using `pd.read_excel()` method.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel (r'Path where the Excel file is stored\File name.xlsx', sheet_name='your Excel sheet name')
print (df)
```